# How can I get an id for a new record in a generic way? (JOOQ 3.4 with Postgres)

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

With jooq 3.4 I can't figure out how to do this (with Postgresql):

```
Query query = dsl.insertInto(TABLE)
    .set(TABLE.ID, Sequences.TABLE_ID_SEQ.nextval());
```

but in a case when I don't know which is the exact table, something like this:

```
TableImpl<?> tableImpl;

Query query = dsl.insertInto(tableImpl)
    .set(tableImpl.getIdentity(), tableImpl.getIdentity().getSequence().nextval());
```

Is it somehow possible?

I tried this:

```
dsl.insertInto(tableImpl)
    .set(DSL.field("id"), 
        tableImpl.getSchema().getSequence("table_id_seq").nextval())
```

This works but I still don't know how to get the sequence name from the TableImpl object.

Is there a solution for this? Or is there a problem with my approach?

In plain SQL I would do this:

```
insert into table_A (id) VALUES nextval('table_A_id_seq');
insert into table_B (table_A_id, some_val) VALUES (currval('table_A_id_seq'), some_val);
```

So I need the value or a reference to that id for later use of the id that was generated for the inserted record as default, but I don't want to set any other values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jOOQ currently doesn't have any means of associating a table with its implicitly used sequence for the identity column. The reason for this is that the sequence is generated when the table is created, but it isn't formally connected to that table.

Usually, you don't have to explicitly set the `serial` value of a column in a PostgreSQL database. It is generated automatically on insert. In terms of DDL, this means:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname SERIAL
);
```

is equivalent to specifying:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq;
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
);
ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
```

The above is taken from:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

In other words, just leave out the `ID` values from the `INSERT` statements.

### "Empty" `INSERT` statements

Note that if you want to create an "empty" `INSERT` statement, i.e. a statement where you pass no values at all, generating a new column with a generated ID, you can use the `DEFAULT VALUES` clause.

**With SQL**

```sql
INSERT INTO tablename DEFAULT VALUES
```

**With jOOQ**

```sql
DSL.using(configuration)
   .insertInto(TABLENAME)
   .defaultValues()
   .execute();
```

### Returning IDs

Note that PostgreSQL has native support for an `INSERT .. RETURNING` clause, which is also supported by jOOQ:

**With SQL**

```sql
INSERT INTO tablename (...) VALUES (...) RETURNING ID
```

**With jOOQ**

```sql
DSL.using(configuration)
   .insertInto(TABLENAME, ...)
   .values(...)
   .returning(TABLENAME.ID)
   .fetchOne();
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I know that PostgreSQL generates ids automatically on insert, but I'd like to have these ID values or a reference for usage in other inserts. I'll edit the question and add an example.

Comment: @Zoltan.Tamasi: I see. Perhaps calling `INSERT .. RETURNING` will help, there? See the updated answer

Comment: Please look at my update at the end of the question.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about the .defaultValues() method. With .returning(TABLE.ID) these almost solve my problem. It would be best, though if I need not to execute the first insert to get the id and use that id explicitly, but to somehow be able to do this in a batch insert.

Comment: @Zoltan.Tamasi: Well, jOOQ doesn't offer you the table to sequence mapping. But you know your database, so you can create a configuration for that...

Comment: Yes, I'll do exactly that.